# Как отсортировать двухмерный массив по количеству нулей в строке?

Tags: python, сортировка, numpy

Есть массив, некоторые элементы которого, могут быть равны нулю. Нужно отсортировать его по количеству нулей в строках, где строка с наибольшим количеством нулей будет последней, а с наименьшим (или без) - первой.

```
arr = np.array([[0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.13, 0.38],
                [2.25, 10.32, 0.00, 0.49, 7.47],
                [3.81, 0.00, 0.00, 1.75, 4.21],
                [0.00, 0.00, 3.22, 0.00, 0.00]]);
```

В результате должно получиться:

```
[[2.25, 1.32, 0.0, 0.49, 7.47],
[3.81, 0.0, 0.0, 1.75, 4.21],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.38],
[0.0, 0.0, 3.22, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = arr[(arr==0).sum(axis=1).argsort()]
```

результат:

```
In [178]: res
Out[178]: 
array([[ 2.25, 10.32,  0.  ,  0.49,  7.47],
       [ 3.81,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.75,  4.21],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.13,  0.38],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  3.22,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```

Comment: добавил ответ на вопрос с другим вариантом кода, можете подсказать, почему с ним не работает, пожалуйста?

Comment: @TedMosby, нет, это уже по сути другой вопрос. Изначальный вопрос был в том как отсортировать 2D Numpy матрицу по количеству нулей - я показал идиоматический способ. Вопрос о том почему не работает ваш вариант кода - это совсем другой вопрос. Мне проще и приятнее показать как сделать правильно чем разбираться в полотне чужого кода)

Comment: хорошо, тогда создам новый вопрос для того, чтобы найти рабочий способ сортировки для моего кода